# Google Map works in HTML but will not display on hosted website

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've established my API and set up billing so there is no limit on views. I used google's developer page to put this together, and it displays and operates just fine when I test the code in my browser, but it fails to display entirely when the page is hosted on my web server. There are no console errors displayed. I've omitted my API key for obvious reasons. Appreciate any help.

HTML & javascript:

```
<head>
    <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
        <div id="map"></div>
        <script>
            function initMap() {
                var newark = {lat: 40.772, lng: -74.170};
                var map = new google.maps.Map(
                    document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 13, center: newark});
                //var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: newark, map: map});
            }
        </script>
        <script async defer 
                src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[myAPIkey]&callback=initMap">
        </script>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#map {
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    height: 600px;
    width: 900px;
    margin-right: 5%;
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: Is the API locked down to certain domains - Working locally on "localhost" is probably fine for google - But unless the "production domain" is whitelisted, the API won't load.

Comment: If you mean Application Restrictions, I had not set any. I set HTTP referrers to my domain and the specific page in question, but it still does not display, and actually disabled the map in my test browser as well. I do not see a category for production domain.

Comment: I apologize for my foolishness. The issue was resulting from not having added my updated css to my cpanel.